# weaker than isoperimetric inequality for surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, geometry, geometric-inequalities

I'm trying to prove, without the aid of the isoperimetric inequality, that for any compact manifold with given surface area $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, that the volume $V$ must be bounded. By this I mean that any sequence of homeomorphisms that also preserve $S$, can't result in an unbounded volume $V$.

In particular, I'm searching for an elementary proof of a weaker-than-isoperimetric inequality:

$$ V \leq f(S) \tag{*}$$

I tried to find such an inequality using the Pappus Centroid Theorem but I have not been successful so far.

**Note 1:** I am interested in a result that generalises easily to compact manifolds in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that aren't necessarily differentiable.

**Note 2:** My motivation comes from a problem in mathematical physics where an isoperimetric inequality is deduced so I don't want to assume the isoperimetric inequality beforehand.

Comment: For surface of revolution, you can see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel's_Horn#Theorem

Comment: @Paul I am aware that the converse of Gabriel's Horn is false which is why I tried using the Pappus Centroid Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing this with Tony Carbery, an analysis professor at Edinburgh, I realised that the Loomis-Whitney inequality answers this problem adequately. In their [original paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1949-55-10/S0002-9904-1949-09320-5/S0002-9904-1949-09320-5.pdf) which is only two pages long they use cubical projections of n-space to demonstrate the following theorem:

> Let $m$ be the measure of an open subset O of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let
>   $m_1,..m_n$ be  the (n-1)-dimensional measures of the projections of O
>   on the coordinate hyper-planes. Then:
>
> $$m^{n-1} \leq \prod_{i=1}^{n} m_i \tag{*}$$

From this we may deduce that if $M$ is a compact manifold in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with given surface area $S$:

$$V \leq S^{3/2} \tag{**}$$

This is precisely the result I wanted.

**Note 1:** I can reproduce the details of their proof here but I think that the original paper is worth reading.

**Note 2:** This is clearly weaker than the sharp isoperimetric bound $V \leq \frac{S^{3/2}}{3 \sqrt{4 \pi}} \huge$ which is much more difficult to prove.